# Meanig of 'has a look about'

Tags: meaning-in-context

Paul **has a mischievous look about him**.

Is it means Paul looked around with a mischievous expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Here, *look* = 'appearance'. The idea is that if somebody looks at Paul, they might conclude that he is mischievous (maybe always, or maybe just at this moment).

*Look* (in this meaning) is not the same as *expression*, although it might include one's expression. *Look* is broader and can include anything from clothes, to hair, to weight, as well as facial expressions.

*About him* is an idiomatic phrase which is not strictly necessary for the meaning of the sentence, but sounds very natural.

Answer (score 0):

> Paul has a mischievous look about him.

means that Paul looks mischievous, that is, as if he has mischief in mind.

It could mean what you suggest if it said

Paul took a mischievous look around.  or

Paul looked about/around mischievously.